# Flutter web redirection with Azure web app

Tags: flutter, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to upload flutter web via Azure web app. Currently I am facing an issue with internal routing issue.

Azure app service with Linux operating system.

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to New Site" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url=".*" />
                     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

staticwebapp.config.json

```
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "route": "/*",
            "redirect": "/index.html",
            "statusCode": 200
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [documentation](https://medium.com/flutter-community/deploy-flutter-web-app-to-azure-app-service-with-node-js-b0781fc6def2) to create and deploy a Flutter web app on Azure App Service.

We need to generate a build file for the deployment process. To do this, run the command.

```
flutter build web
```

I ran the following commands to install Node.js in Flutter web app:

```
npm install -g express-generator   
npm install express
```

**app.js**

```js
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");

var app = express();

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build/web")));
module.exports = app;
```

**index.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <title>Flutter Web App</title>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body>   
    <div id="flutter_web_app"></div>
    <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**lib/main.dart**:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Web App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomePage(),
        '/about': (context) => AboutPage(),
        '/contact': (context) => ContactPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Welcome to the Home Page!'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/about');
              },
              child: Text('Go to About Page'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AboutPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('About'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('This is the About Page.'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/contact');
              },
              child: Text('Go to Contact Page'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ContactPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Contact'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('You can contact us here.'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
              },
              child: Text('Go to Home Page'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I ran the commands below to run the Flutter app.

```
flutter run
```

**Local Output**:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I successfully deployed my build/web file to the Azure web app using Visual Studio Code Azure Extension.

[image]

[image]

Below is the output from the Azure web app.
[image]

I was successfully redirected to the other pages.

[image]

[image]